# oracle escape function

Tags: oracle, escaping, sql-injection

Are there any function in oracle that escapes wrong characters in sql query? I have code that builds query from different string, and some of them may contain `'` character, this breaks sql query.

Comment: you don't mention the language you use...

Comment: hmm, I think functions that are accessible from sql queries are also accessible in pl/sql, but if that is important: it's pl/sql

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Yahia points out, you should *always* use bind variables rather than dynamically assembling SQL statements dynamically.  That's the proper way to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.  Escaping a string provides a far lower level of protection.

That being said, assuming you're using Oracle 10.1 or later, you can use the q quoting syntax.  Something like

```
  1  select q'[This is a string with an embedded ']' str
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

STR
-----------------------------------
This is a string with an embedded '
```

You can replace the [ and ] characters with a number of other characters depending on what characters might appear in the string

```
  1  select q'<This is a string with an embedded '>' str
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

STR
-----------------------------------
This is a string with an embedded '

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select q'{This is a string with an embedded '}' str
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

STR
-----------------------------------
This is a string with an embedded '
```

Comment: While it is a nice workaround, It would fail if the string contains the characters `]'`... :)

Comment: @Vincent - Quite right.  The first would fail if there was a ], the second would fail if there was a >, the third would fail if there was a }.  You have to pick an enclosure character that will not occur in the string itself.

Comment: this feature is great and it's very useful when you have to use log4j backed by jdbc

Comment: +1 for recommending bind variables, but answering the question anyway. :D I'm working on a big app migration from MySQL to Oracle, and it doesn't use prepared statements, just string escaping. This will be a lifesaver while migrating. Hope to convert it to binding variables in the future.

Answer (score 3):

you should never build queries from strings - use parameters instead... otherwise there is always a chance that somebody finds a way to inject some SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Two single quote together escapes a single quote. So use `''` in place of `'` in your string.

Comment: This question is about using the alternative quoting mechanism signified by `q'` at the start.  This won't work using that mechanism.